# How to deploy a jax-rs web service to apache tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have troubles deploying a sample web service for my desktop application to tomcat.

Here are my classes

AppConfig.java

```
@ApplicationPath("sample-ws")
public class AppConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(HelloWorld.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
@Path("hello-world")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>sample-ws</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I don't know what to write in my web.xml, and I can't get this thing work. What do I miss?

P.S. In case that's important, I'm using apache-tomcat-8.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.xml you should add a listener for starting up the framework, and the url mappings for your webservices. Have a look at this article: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

However, your web.xml should look similar to this:

```
<web-app>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```